# Actions on Google Node.js SDK v2: conv.ask() with Object as Argument

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google

When I need a **simple response** having **suggestion buttons**, the following code works totally fine with v2 of the AoG SDK:

```
conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
    speech: 'blabla',
    text: 'display text',
}), new Suggestions(['Suggestion 1', 'Suggestion 2']));
```

But: There are cases where I have the complete response prepared as JSON saved in an external file and want to use this as input parameter for ask():

```
conv.ask({
    simpleResponse: {
        textToSpeech: 'blabla',
        displayText: 'display text',
    },
    suggestions: [
        { title: 'Suggestion 1' },
        { title: 'Suggestion 2' },
    ],
});
```

The problem is that the **suggestion buttons are not displayed**.
I am using TypeScript and the object passed to ask() has a valid `Response` type.

In **v1** of the AoG SDK I could do the following (the argument `ask()` gets is no valid `Response` object and does not work in v2):

```
app.ask({
    items: [{
        simpleResponse: {
            textToSpeech: 'blabla',
            displayText: 'display text',
        }
    }],
    suggestions: [
        { title: 'Suggestion 1' },
        { title: 'Suggestion 2' },
    ]
});
```

**Does anyone know how I could do that for v2?**

Comment: Regarding the way it works on V2, do you have to store it as a JSON and not a JS Object like in your first example? In this case it would work

Comment: I have to store it as a JSON (it's within a translation file)

Comment: Can you split up the ask into two parts: conv.ask(simpleResponse) and conv.ask(suggestions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`RichResponseOptions`](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/interfaces/conversation_response.richresponseoptions.html) type to store a RichResponse as pure JSON using the raw [`GoogleActionsV2RichResponseItem`](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/interfaces/actionssdk_api_v2.googleactionsv2richresponseitem.html) type for RichResponse items.

`response.json`

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "simpleResponse": {
        "textToSpeech": "blabla",
        "displayText": "display text"
      }
    }
  ],
  "suggestions": [
    "Suggestion 1",
    "Suggestion 2"
  ]
}
```

`app.js`

```es6
const { dialogflow, RichResponse } = require('actions-on-google')

// load the response as JSON
const response = require('./response.json')

const app = dialogflow()

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.ask(new RichResponse(response))
})
```

By sending anonymous objects into `conv.ask`, the library interprets them as raw RichResponse **items**. So it does work when you are sending SimpleResponses. To send multiple raw RichResponse items, you would need separate elements for each item and call `conv.ask` multiple times or spread them into a single `conv.ask`.

```es6
conv.ask({
  simpleResponse: {
    textToSpeech: 'blabla',
    displayText: 'display text',
  }
})
conv.ask({
  simpleResponse: {
    textToSpeech: 'blabla',
    displayText: 'display text',
  }
})
```

But as you noticed, suggestions are **not** RichResponse items as they are directly part of the RichResponse object itself. You need to construct the entire RichResponse object in order to put suggestions in.

You can find the entire list of currently valid raw values for RichResponse items [here](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/interfaces/actionssdk_api_v2.googleactionsv2richresponseitem.html).